# Was Leia supposed to enlist Obi-Wan Kenobi's help anyway?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Since Leia's corvette was overtaken and captured by Vader's Star Destroyer, she figured out that Kenobi was "her only hope" to get Death Star plans to her father on Alderaan.

- Was linking up with Kenobi part of the original plan, or did that only come out because of her ship's capture?
- If it wasn't part of the plan, how did it manage to happen that her ship was captured exactly over Tatooine, which is a random hole in the underbelly of the Galaxy?

Answers from Disney or Legends canon please.

Comment: Yes, the intention was that in their darkest time of need, they were going to collect their biggest big gun from where they'd hidden him

Comment: @Richard They were going to retrieve.... *Jar-Jar*?

Comment: His wacky antics would undoubtedly have helped them destroy the death star.

Comment: @Richard Which is clearly why their next stop was Alderaan, and why the Death Star also went there, as seen here: https://youtu.be/qBAZGtBfcY4

Comment: @DVK Don't underestimate the _power_ of the... clumsy side!

Comment: @Dronz - I love it. And now I don't feel so sorry about the planet getting zapped.

Comment: @DVK: as a measure to torture Vader…[—it works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdS2kCUGvfo)

Comment: @JaneS - and may the KLUTZ be with you!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Leia's message via Artoo is:

> General Kenobi, years ago you served 
>                            my father in the Clone Wars. Now he 
>                            begs you to help him in his struggle 
>                            against the Empire. **I regret that I 
>                            am unable to present my father's 
>                            request to you in person**, but my 
>                            ship has fallen under attack and I'm 
>                            afraid my mission to bring you to 
>                            Alderaan has failed. I have placed 
>                            information vital to the survival of 
>                            the Rebellion into the memory systems 
>                            of this R2 unit. My father will know 
>                            how to retrieve it. You must see 
>                            this droid safely delivered to him 
>                            on Alderaan. This is our most 
>                            desperate hour. Help me, Obi-Wan 
>                            Kenobi, you're my only hope.

So she was going to Tatooine to see Kenobi anyway.

Comment: So does she not say who she is in the message? Is Obi-Wan supposed to recognize her on sight after not seeing her for 18 years, or just use the force to know he's supposed to take R2 to Bail Organa? lol

Comment: Although I suppose R2 knew who she was and could tell them that, although C3PO says he didn't know who she was

Comment: @childcat15 "A guy I served in the Clone Wars, who lives on Alderaan, and is anti-Empire... Oh, that must mean Organa"

Comment: "you served **my father** in the Clone Wars ... You must see this droid safely delivered **to him on Alderaan**" - how many people did Obi-Wan serve during the war who were associated with Alderaan and had a female child at that time?  And considering that Obi-Wan was present when Leia was given to Bail to hide on Alderaan at the end of Episode 3.

Comment: Princess Leia is a _princess_. She is bound to assume that she is famous and that people recognize her when they see her.

Comment: I guess it is safe to assume at the time of that recording she did not know who her real father was. But she was aware that she was adopted by the Organa family. And when she says "father" she is referring to her adoptive father.

Comment: @childcat15: I seem to recall that the novelization has a message introduction, something like "Greetings in haste to General Kenobi from Leia Organa _titles_".

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

According to the [new canon novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/A_New_Hope:_The_Princess,_the_Scoundrel,_and_the_Farm_Boy) of Star Wars: A New Hope, linking up with Kenobi on Tatooine was a major part of Bail Organa's plan. Leia was supposed to "seek him out" and bring him to her father:

> Admitting she failed made the words taste bitter in her mouth. Though
>   she and the crew of the Tantive IV had downloaded the information and
>   made the jump to Tatooine, she wouldn’t be able to complete the second
>   part of the mission. **Her father had requested that she seek out an old
>   friend, one General Kenobi, because, in his own words, “a war demanded
>   warriors” to fight.** A legendary Jedi Knight, Kenobi had gone into
>   secret exile on the remote desert planet to avoid the deadly purge
>   that had wiped out his order.

---

We also learn from Rogue One that bringing Kenobi back into the fight was something that was discussed (between Mon Mothma and Bail Organa) before Leia was even involved.